# HTML5 Video - How to detect when a specific part of the video has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am loading a video with HTML5, and watching the progress event like this:

```
var progressEventHandler=function(e){

};
var cn,domTarget='#vid';
cn=$(domTarget);
cn[0].addEventListener('progress',progressEventHandler,false);
```

I only want to play part of this video. And I want to know when that part has fully loaded. I am not interested in knowing when the entire video has loaded, just this part.

My question is this:

Is there any way of using the progress event to find out when a certain amount of the video has been loaded?

Would I be right in assuming that 50% of the file loaded would equate to being able to play the first half of the video?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Use `buffered` property of the `HTMLMediaElement`.

> The ranges of the media source that the browser has buffered (if any)
>   at the moment the buffered property is accessed.
>   The returned `TimeRanges` object is normalized.
>
> [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)

Simple example to show the usage:

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');
...
// Attach this to any event. Note that only first range is printed.
var buffered = video.buffered;
console.log(
  'The browser has buffered: ' + buffered.start(0) + ' - ' + buffered.end(0) + ' sec'
);
```